# How to Run Homebrew's Caskroom/cask/pdfinfo?

Tags: pdf, homebrew

I run `brew install Caskroom/cask/pdfinfo` but I cannot find in my commandline. My PATH is

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

---

How can you run `pdfinfo` of Homebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew cask installs `pdfinfo` in

```
/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/pdfinfo/latest/PDFInfo.app
```

And then creates a symbolic link to this locations in:

```
~/Applications
```

You can run installed `pdfinfo` with:

```
open -a pdfinfo
```

or

```
open -a /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/pdfinfo/latest/PDFInfo.app
```

or

```
open -a ~/Applications/PDFInfo.app
```

Simply you can open app with double click on `~/Applications/PDFInfo.app` icon.

Comment: Why it works like that? Why you cannot run it just with `pdfinfo` like in Linux? I need to bind it to my Unix scripts, and would not like to give OSX special attention.

Comment: @Masi because cask treats in AppStore way with applications. It creates `.app` applications that can be moved into `/Applications`. The `~/Applications` path is user-specific applications instead of system applications (`/Applications`). You can run it with this address `~/Applications/PDFInfo.app/Contents/MacOS/PDFInfo` directly from terminal. Or add `~/Applications/PDFInfo.app/Contents/MacOS/` to your $PATH or simply create an alias for `PDFInfo` command in your script to this path.

Comment: Why is there no `pdfinfo` terminal tool in Homebrew?

Comment: @Masi It can be done with Automator workflows that is described here : http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113092/117407 and Automator workflows can be invoked from terminal: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060805092715125 You can combine these if you want. Unfortunately I am not familiar with better command line utility for this purpose.